# Is there any tool for generating Hamiltonian for circuit-QED?

Tags: resource-request, superconducting-quantum-computing

There are tools like QuTip helping you simulate a given Hamiltonian. However, I am wondering if is there any tool/library or something that takes e.g. a graph (G, V, E) of qubits and resonators, and returns a Hamiltonian. It does not have to be graph though, it can be anything, simply returning "approximated Hamiltonian" from the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question directly, but Docplex, which is IBM's Decision Optimization CPLEX Modeling for Python is capable of generating an Ising hamiltonian from a cost function. Take a look at this qiskit [tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/advanced/aqua/optimization/docplex.ipynb).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not really, this library transforms an optimization problem into the QUBO/Ising model. It has nothing to do with the actual Hamiltonian and qubit structure.

Answer (score 0):

So if it's like -

- You have an arbitrary (L,C) circuit
- And want to quantize it and get a Hamiltonian matrix

Then you could use [QuCAT](https://qucat.org/) (Quantum Circuit Analyzer Tool), a python library developed by people at Delft University. It can even handle resistors, and it'll compute the associated decay operators, too!

If, however, you have some arbitrary geometry with distributed elements like transmission lines,  resonators etc, you could explore IBM's Qiskit Metal.